# Parsing a text file to SQLite so the data can be queried using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, parsing, parser-generator

Using objective-c I am looking to parse a varying number of text files to a SQLite database to then query this data.  The text will be in the below format:

```
PokerStars Hand #74875631942:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - 2012/02/01 17:08:58 ET
Table 'Psyche II' 2-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 1: demaredemare ($100 in chips) 
Seat 2: Bren Stokes ($100 in chips) 
Bren Stokes: posts small blind $0.50
demaredemare: posts big blind $1
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to Bren Stokes [Th 9d]
Bren Stokes: raises $2 to $3
demaredemare: folds 
Uncalled bet ($2) returned to Bren Stokes
Bren Stokes collected $2 from pot
Bren Stokes: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $2 | Rake $0 
Seat 1: demaredemare (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 2: Bren Stokes (button) (small blind) collected ($2)



PokerStars Hand #74875657847:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - 2012/02/01 17:09:23 ET
Table 'Psyche II' 2-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: demaredemare ($99 in chips) 
Seat 2: Bren Stokes ($101 in chips) 
demaredemare: posts small blind $0.50
Bren Stokes: posts big blind $1
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to Bren Stokes [9d Qs]
demaredemare: raises $1 to $2
Bren Stokes: calls $1
*** FLOP *** [Tc Ah 8c]
Bren Stokes: checks 
demaredemare: bets $2
Bren Stokes: calls $2
*** TURN *** [Tc Ah 8c] [4c]
Bren Stokes: checks 
demaredemare: checks 
*** RIVER *** [Tc Ah 8c 4c] [4s]
Bren Stokes: checks 
demaredemare: checks 
*** SHOW DOWN ***
Bren Stokes: shows [9d Qs] (a pair of Fours)
demaredemare: shows [3d Qh] (a pair of Fours)
Bren Stokes collected $3.82 from pot
demaredemare collected $3.82 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $8 | Rake $0.36 
Board [Tc Ah 8c 4c 4s]
Seat 1: demaredemare (button) (small blind) showed [3d Qh] and won ($3.82) with a pair of     Fours
Seat 2: Bren Stokes (big blind) showed [9d Qs] and won ($3.82) with a pair of Fours
```

As i need to 'pull' out varying bits of information from each line I believe i'm going to need to use a parser to do this?  However I've seen some code such as:
NSString stringWithContentsOfFile
NSArray fileContents componentsSeparatedByString
NSMutableDictionary
NSScanner
NSBundle
......what way do you guys think would be best to approach and solve this?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Love your work!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an established parser generator to generate both a lexer and a parser for your input string. Parsing it manually is more likely to be error-prone and hard to maintain.

As for the question of which generator to use, you can probably afford to pick and choose a bit. The important thing if you choose to go this path is to produce a grammar for the input string. Once you have that grammar worked out in some variant of BNF you should be easily able to convert it to whatever generator you choose.

If you can consider using a bit of C++ mixed in you could use Boost.spirit. To develop the grammar itself, you could just use the tried-and-tested flex/bison route to get things up and running quickly.